# How do I write an application launcher that will start Atom in a custom working directory?

Tags: application, .desktop

I am maintaining a Jekyll-powered blog and on my local machine its git repository is located at `/home/fusion809/GitHub/fusion809.github.io` to edit it in Atom I have created this application launcher (which is saved at `/home/fusion809/.local/share/applications/edblog.desktop`):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=edblog
GenericName=edblog
Type=Application;
Categories=TextEditor;Atom
Exec=atom ~/GitHub/fusion809.github.io
TryExec=/usr/bin/atom ~/GitHub/fusion809.github.io
Icon=atom.png
```

For a reason that escapes me whenever I run `edblog.desktop` by double-clicking it I get an error message:

```
Failed to execute file "edblog":
Invalid desktop file
```

I have tried substituting `~` with `$HOME` and `/home/fusion809` to no effect.

Comment: I recommend using `Exec=atom /home/fusion809/GitHub/fusion809.github.io`. By the way is command `atom /home/fusion809/GitHub/fusion809.github.io` working fine from Terminal? Also make sure that your `.desktop` file has execution permission.

Comment: Just tried that (resetting `Exec`) and it didn't work. As for the permissions it is set to be executable (which I did by running `sudo chmod +x edblog.desktop`). The command `atom /home/fusion809/GitHub/fusion809.github.io` works fine from terminal, in fact, I have been executing it without a problem for months now as I defined it as a function that is also called `edblog` in my `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: What is odd though is that running the edblog launcher from my application menu goes without a hitch but when I open my file browser (atm Thunar) and click on my edblog.desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications` it returns that error message. Running other launchers in this directory goes without a hitch, however.

Comment: So, is `.desktop` file executing fine from command-line? (ex: `exo-open /path/to/.desktop`)? then problem seems with thunar file manager.

Comment: Well I'll be, you're right, it is to do with my file manager, although it seems to affect all my file managers, not just Thunar. Well you right up this answer and I will accept it.